# external js-files don't know each other

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very long external JS-file which I want to split in 2 seperate JS-files. The problem with this is, that `file_1.js` doesn't know the functions of `file_2.js` anymore. Is there something special I don't have in mind when I'm doing this.

```
<script src="js/file_1.js"></script>
<script src="js/file_2.js"></script>
```

head of my html.

and I'm loading every content in a document ready.

```
$(function() { some code in both });
```

Cheers

Comment: try reverse the script tags, declare file_1.js after file_2.js: <script src="js/file_2.js"></script>
<script src="js/file_1.js"></script>

Comment: where are you putting your document.ready?  Put it after both files have loaded.  If all your files are doing are defining functions (in the global scope) and not calling anything immediately, you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript files can only access code from files that are loaded before them. In this example file2 can access functions in file1, but not the other way around.

If they each need to access each other, you have a circular dependency. When this happens, it usually means your two files should really just be one big one.

Comment: yeah, the problem is that my editor gets so slow at a file with about 3100 lines. I tried to change them, that `file_2.js` loads first, but it didnt help.

Comment: These files are compressed?

Comment: Can you divide the code logically so that functions in file2 only depend on file1, and not vice versa? That may be difficult, but it will make your code much easier to maintain.

Comment: Since you are using "$(function() { some code in both });" these functions will be executed when all content are loaded on page, so file_1.js is loaded and file_2.js is loaded. Maybe you have something that in local scope in the file_1.js for example?

Comment: Thanks for the loading order tip.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, calling the external js file which declares the functions before the external js which calls the functions is what you need to do.

Have you tried calling one of the functions from within the dom? If that fails as well, there may be issues with how you broke up the js.

```
<script src="js/file_2.js"></script>
<script src="js/file_1.js"></script>
```

vs

```
<script src="js/file_2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         someFunctionWithinFile_2();
    });
</script>
```